# How to test that method has added redirectAttributes ?(by MockMvc)

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, junit, mocking

I have wrote this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=GET)
public String myMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("rd", "rdValue");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("fa", faValue);
   return "redirect:/someOtherURL";
}
```

Test code:

```
    @Test
    public void myMethod() throws Exception{

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/someURL");
    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);
}
```

If I invoke test execution I see:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.myMethod(org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuControllerTest.myMethod(VacancyMenuControllerTest.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.myMethod(org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:322)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    ... 43 more
```

I understand that problem with RedirectAttributes, But I don't understand how to solve it.

By MockMvc how to test that redirectAttributes contains  `rd` and `fa` ?

I use **3.2.3.RELEASE** spring framework version

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`MockMvcResultMatchers#flash()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#flash%28%29) which returns a [`FlashAttributeResultMatchers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/FlashAttributeResultMatchers.html) object which has an [`attribute()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/FlashAttributeResultMatchers.html#attribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/someURL"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("rd", "rdValue"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.flash().attribute("fa", someValueThatEqualsFaValue));
```

Note that `"rd"` will be a `Model` attribute, not a flash attribute.

Comment: @user2740224 What version of Spring are you using? `RedirectAttributes` were added in 3.1. Also, You should edit your question with errors you get, they don't format well in comments.

Comment: Topic has upsated. I use 3.2.3.RELEASE spring framework version