# In test: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, redirect

I trying to test this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateVacancy", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public String updateVacancyPRG(Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,@RequestParam("idVacancy") Integer idVacancy ){
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "Submitted Correctly at "+ new Date());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("idVacancy",idVacancy);
        return "redirect:goToVacancyDetails";
    }
```

test code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfigUI.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class VacancyMenuControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    VacancyMenuController vacancyMenuController;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;



    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

    }
    @Test
    public void updateVacancyPRG() throws Exception{

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/updateVacancy");
        request.param("idVacancy", "1");
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);//exception from this line

    }
  ...
}
```

exception text:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.updateVacancyPRG(org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,java.lang.Integer)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuControllerTest.updateVacancyPRG(VacancyMenuControllerTest.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.updateVacancyPRG(org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,java.lang.Integer)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:322)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    ... 43 more
```

I am confused.

Can you help me?

**I use 3.2.3.RELEASE spring framework version**

BeanConfigUI.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based 
        configuration) -->
    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers" />

    <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />
    <!-- <import resource="security_config.xml" /> -->


     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RedirectAttributes` were added in Spring 3.1. This interface extends `Model`, but it is not supported by previous versions of Spring as it adds additional behavior that isn't present.

In your `BeanConfigUI.xml` add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and the additional namespace declarations. Without, I believe `MockMvc` uses a `FrameworkServlet` instead of the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I haven't ways for test this method using mock mvc?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Test what? Flash attributes? Of course there is. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274105/how-to-test-that-method-has-added-redirectattributes-by-mockmvc).

Comment: I don't understand You.When I invoke mockMvc.perform(request) I get exception. What way for avoid exception. In material for link person hase same exception

Comment: I can not send http request. How I can test something?

Comment: use spring version 3.2

Comment: @user2740224 Show your `MockMvc` configuration, please.

Comment: @user We're going to go a little deeper. Post your `BeanConfigUI.xml` file too.

Comment: in data.xml - hibernate configuration only.

Comment: @user2740224 So as I've stated in the other answer, just add `<mvc:annotation-driven>`.

Comment: after adding <mvc:annotation-driven> all good work. thanks a lot. spring show very uninformal exception.

Comment: I don't know anything about FrameworkServlet. I don't see it in my project.

Comment: why this problem appears only if I use RedirectAttributes? other work and without this annotation? if You can  - please add information to answer.

Comment: @user2740224 `FrameworkServlet` is the parent class of `DispatcherServlet`. Its configuration for handling requests is more limited than `DispatcherServlets` and apparently it doesn't support `RedirectAttributes`. With `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, the `MokcMvc` only uses the `FrameworkServlet`. The documentation should explain how `mvc:annotation-driven` works, I just don't have it in front of me now.