# Mock the @ModelAttribute in the request handler of spring controller without using request paramter approach

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I need to mock the `@ModelAttribute` in the request handler of spring controller. I hope to pass diverse values via mock instead of passsing it via MockMVC request parameter. There is a request interceptor which works  and possibly is nullyfying even the model object attribute is paased via request parameter hence this question.

So below is the partial code snippet; 
Componet1: Controller whose request handler's @ModelAtrribute is to be mocked.

@Controller public class MyController {
/** some code here*/

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/myRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String requestHanderForMyRequest(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute(name="myBean") People person) {
    ...
    Date birthDate = person.getBirthDate();
    ...
    // do something with date
    /** prepare JSON response and return */
    return "{ ...}";
}
```

}

Component 2: DateFieldInterceptor.java 
Intercepts date field in request and processes it and then updates it if success flow otherwise resets to null.

Component 3: Mock test method in JUnit test class

```
@Test
public void testRequestHanderForMyRequest() {
    try {
        ResponseInstance responseInstance = testUtility .loadResponseFromFile("testFile.json");

        Assert.assertNotNull("No base data", responseInstance);

        MvcResult resultantMvc = mockMvc.perform(post("/myRequest")
                                                    .session(mockHttpSession)
                                                .param(START_DATE, START_DATE_VALUE)
                                                .param("birthdate", BIRTH_DATE_VALUE)
                                                .param("personName", "dfs edfsd")
                                                )
                                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$").exists())
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isNotEmpty())
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasKey(PAYLOAD)))
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)))
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath(JSON_PATH_ROOT_PAYLOAD).isArray())
                                        .andExpect(jsonPath(JSON_PATH_ROOT_PAYLOAD).isNotEmpty())
                                        .andReturn();
        Assert.assertNotNull(MVC_RESULT_IS_MISSING_FOR_THE_REQUEST, resultantMvc);

        String payloadData = resultantMvc.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Assert.assertTrue(RESPONSE_IS_MISSING_PAYLOAD_DATA, StringUtils.isNotBlank(payloadData));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The date interceptor is somehow going to negative flow and resetting the date field to null.
I wish to unit test the birthdate field of People instance.
If I can somehow mock the person.getBirthDate() then I should be alright with the unit test.
But mocks don't seem to work for @ModelAttribute parameters.

Comment: try to add your test code

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, Thanks for you input. I have added seudo code.

Comment: how do you create the mockMvc object?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, I have autowired MockMvc.

Comment: I am now able to bypass this issue. 
Using [flash][1] attribute the value of date attribute is retained.       I added my testModelObject as  .flashAttribute("myBean", testModelObject) in the mockMVc instance in my unit test method.
See comments in following example [Example][2] .

I am still looking for effective way to mock @ModelAttribute though.


  [1]: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e1595
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274105/how-to-test-that-method-has-added-redirectattributes-by-mockmvc